# Hibernate Search 6 with multitenancy issue, HSEARCH000520, HSEARCH600029

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm testing Hibernate Search 6 multitenancy with Hibernate (referred to [this link](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/06/15/jakarta-ee-multitenancy-with-jpa-on-wildfly-part-1/)) and got error message "HSEARCH000520: Hibernate Search encountered failures during bootstrap", with additional detail,
"HSEARCH600029: Invalid backend configuration: index 'Users' requires multi-tenancy but no multi-tenancy strategy is set".

I apply to my Users entity. Here is the Users entity class.

```
@Indexed
public class Users implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 

    @JsonbTransient
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @FullTextField(analyzer = "name", projectable = Projectable.YES)
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    
    ...
    
}
```

And persistance.xml

```
  <persistence-unit name="jakartaEEPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/myDS</jta-data-source> 
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> 
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties> 
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
      ...
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
       
      <property name="hibernate.search.backend.directory.root" value="/home/peter/hbsearch/"/>
      <property name="hibernate.search.backend.io.commit_interval" value="500"/>
      <property name="hibernate.search.backend.directory.type" value="local-filesystem"/>
      <property name="hibernate.search.backend.analysis.configurer" value="com.hibernateLuceneSearch.AnalyzerConfigurator"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="none"/>
      <property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="DATABASE"/>
      <property name="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value="com.dao.multitenancy.DatabaseTenantResolver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value="com.dao.multitenancy.DatabaseMultiTenantProvider"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

Is there any missing or incorrect in this entity class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly pick a multi-tenancy strategy in your backend. Just add this property to your `persistence.xml`:

```
      <property name="hibernate.search.backend.multi_tenancy.strategy" value="discriminator"/>
```

See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-lucene-multi-tenancy

**EDIT**: I created [HSEARCH-4163](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-4163) to try to change this admittedly unhelpful error message.

**EDIT 2**: Explicitly configuring the multi-tenancy strategy is no longer required in Hibernate Search 6.1; see https://in.relation.to/2021/09/10/hibernate-search-6-1-0-Alpha1/#other-changes

Comment: @PeterL355 No problem. Don't forgeet to mark the solution as accepted, so it can help others to spot it more easily.