# Hibernate Search with JNDI

Tags: hibernate, multi-tenant, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate Search 6 with multitenancy (refer to [Hibernate Search 6 with multitenancy issue, HSEARCH000520, HSEARCH600029](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66303479/6692043)). My environment: Hibernate ORM 5.4.28, Hibernate Search 6.0.2, Payara server 2021.1, and MariaDb. I configured with 2 datasources(2 databases) - myDS and my2ndDS. I can use the multitenancy resolver method below in finding/merging entity by referencing to a tenant id successfully. This method I applied to the search too(see coding below). Now the problem is when I search something will show error below.

```
@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

public EntityManager getEM(final String tenantId) {
    final SessionFactoryImplementor sf = emf.unwrap(SessionFactoryImplementor.class);

    final MultitenancyResolver tenantResolver = (MultitenancyResolver) sf.getCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver();
    tenantResolver.setTenantIdentifier(tenantId);
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

The hibernate search class/method:

```
    @Stateless
    public class SearchAnnouncementMessage {
      ...
    private EntityManager getEM(final String tenantId) {
     ...
    } 
    public ResultSearchObject searchAnnouncementMsgs(final String tenantId,
            final boolean reindexWithHibernateSearch, final String searchWord,
            final int[] range) {
     ....
          final SearchSession searchSession = Search.session(getEM(tenantId));
            if (reindexWithHibernateSearch) {
                logger.info("Reindex with HibernateSearch");
                try {
                    searchSession.massIndexer()
                            .idFetchSize(150)
                            .batchSizeToLoadObjects(25)
                            .threadsToLoadObjects(THREADS_LOAD_OBJ)
                            .transactionTimeout(SEARCH_TIMEOUT)
                            .startAndWait();
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    logger.info("#1 can't search at this time; error: {}", () -> e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }
            try {
    
                logger.info("search in AnnouncementMsgs");
                final SearchQuery<AnnouncementMsgs> result = searchSession.search(AnnouncementMsgs.class).extension(LuceneExtension.get())
                        .where(f -> f.bool(b -> { 
       ...
    }
}
```

Error message (show at line with Search.session(getEM(tenantId));:

```
#
HSEARCH000058: Exception occurred javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error trying to get datasource ['java:app/jdbc/my2ndDS']
Failing operation:
Fetching identifiers of entities to index for entity 'Users' during mass indexing
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error trying to get datasource ['java:app/jdbc/my2ndDS']
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.uniqueResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1635)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.uniqueResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.massindexing.impl.IdentifierProducer.loadAllIdentifiers(IdentifierProducer.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.massindexing.impl.IdentifierProducer.inTransactionWrapper(IdentifierProducer.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.massindexing.impl.IdentifierProducer.run(IdentifierProducer.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.massindexing.impl.OptionallyWrapInJTATransaction.runWithFailureHandler(OptionallyWrapInJTATransaction.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.massindexing.impl.FailureHandledRunnable.run(FailureHandledRunnable.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.search.util.common.impl.CancellableExecutionCompletableFuture$CompletingRunnable.run(CancellableExecutionCompletableFuture.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error trying to get datasource ['java:app/jdbc/my2ndDS']
    at com.dao.multitenancy.DatabaseMultiTenantProvider.getConnection(DatabaseMultiTenantProvider.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(ContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2103)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2040)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2018)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2849)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2831)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2663)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2658)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.list(StatelessSessionImpl.java:564)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1625)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:app/jdbc/my2ndDS' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation ]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:442)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.dao.multitenancy.DatabaseMultiTenantProvider.getConnection(DatabaseMultiTenantProvider.java:94)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation 
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.getComponentId(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:870)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:737)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:167)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:476)
    ... 39 more
|#]
```

At public class DatabaseMultiTenantProvider (see line number 94, 96; near bottom):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.config.spi.ConfigurationService;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.MultiTenantConnectionProvider;
import org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceRegistryAwareService;
import org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceRegistryImplementor;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource; 
import java.sql.SQLException; 
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class DatabaseMultiTenantProvider implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider, ServiceRegistryAwareService {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String TENANT_SUPPORTED = "DATABASE";
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private String typeTenancy;
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void injectServices(ServiceRegistryImplementor serviceRegistry) {
        logger.debug("injectService for DatabaseMultiTenantProvider");
        typeTenancy = (String) serviceRegistry
                .getService(ConfigurationService.class)
                .getSettings().get("hibernate.multiTenancy");
        logger.debug("datasouce casting result: {}", () -> serviceRegistry.getService(ConfigurationService.class).getSettings().get("hibernate.connection.datasource"));
        if (serviceRegistry
                .getService(ConfigurationService.class)
                .getSettings().get("hibernate.connection.datasource") instanceof DataSource) {
            logger.debug("can cast to DataSource");
            dataSource = (DataSource) serviceRegistry
                    .getService(ConfigurationService.class)
                    .getSettings().get("hibernate.connection.datasource");
        } else {
            logger.debug("can't cast to DataSource; have to use JNDI lookup");
            try {
                final Context init = new InitialContext();
                dataSource = (DataSource) init.lookup((String) serviceRegistry
                        .getService(ConfigurationService.class)
                        .getSettings().get("hibernate.connection.datasource"));
            } catch (final NamingException e) {
                logger.error("error in init lookup: {}", ()->e.getMessage());
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class clazz) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> clazz) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        return connection;

    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {

        
        //Just use the multitenancy if the hibernate.multiTenancy == DATABASE
        logger.debug("connecting to tenent: {}", () -> tenantIdentifier);
        if (TENANT_SUPPORTED.equals(typeTenancy)) {
            try {
 
               final Context  init = new InitialContext();
                logger.debug("use tenant datasource: {}", () -> tenantIdentifier);
                final String ds = "java:app/jdbc/"+tenantIdentifier;
                logger.debug("getConnection for: {}", ()->ds);
                dataSource = (DataSource) init.lookup(ds); //line 94
             } catch (NamingException e) {
                throw new HibernateException("Error trying to get datasource ['java:app/jdbc/" + tenantIdentifier + "']", e);//line 96 
            }
        }
        return dataSource.getConnection();

    }

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        logger.debug("release any connection");
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        logger.debug("release a connection for tenentId: {}", () -> tenantIdentifier);
        releaseAnyConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

I think that the issue should come from JNDI with Hibernate Search. Any idea or a hint much appreciated.

Updated(1): I also tested with new ThreadLocal (see below), still show same errors.

With new ThreadLocal:

```
public  class CallEntityManager {

    private static ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public static EntityManager getEM(final String tenantId) {
        if (emf == null) { 
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jakartaEEPU");
        }  
        final SessionFactoryImplementor sf = emf.unwrap(SessionFactoryImplementor.class);
        final MultitenancyResolver tenantResolver = (MultitenancyResolver) sf.getCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver();
        tenantResolver.setTenantIdentifier(tenantId);
        EntityManager em = threadLocal.get();
        if (em == null) {
            logger.debug("em is null; will create EM now");
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            threadLocal.set(em);
        }
        return em;
    }

    public static void closeEntityManager() {
        final EntityManager em = threadLocal.get();
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
            threadLocal.set(null); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate Search's mass indexer needs to create entity managers itself, because it parallelizes indexing and you can't use one entity manager concurrently in multiple threads. However, it should automatically use the tenant ID of the original session it was created from. And, judging from the error message, it does in your case: there's a reference to `my2ndDS` in there.

As far as I can tell, the problem is in retrieving the datasource, not in handling multi-tenancy. Not that Hibernate Search creates its own threads in the mass-indexer. Does your datasource retrieval rely on thread-local context that may not be initialized in those new threads?

A quick and dirty way to test this would be to create a thread manually (`new Thread()`), and try to invoke `getEM()` from that thread. If you get the same error, the problem is probably that Datasource resolution relies on some uninitialized thread-local context. And then you should investigate the part of the stack trace that you're not showing, below "Lookup failed for 'java:app/jdbc/my2nDS'".

By the way, the `Got null ComponentInvocation` seems characteristic of Payara. This is the first result I got when searching the web: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/2430
If I were you, I'd look into what's going wrong in the JNDI resolution.

Comment: I updated more error messages and provided additional class/method that is related to error.  I also tried with create-jvm-options -Ddeployment.resource.validation=false, but the errors are same.

Comment: @PeterL355 Did you try calling `getEM()` from a thread you created yourself (`new Thread()`) like I suggested? What was the result?

Comment: Note you also need to run a query within that thread in order for Hibernate to try to retrieve the datasource.

Comment: I created/tested with new ThreadLocal<EntityManager> (see updated(1)), but got the same errors pointed to line 94, 96.

Comment: I saw from log: the Hibernate Search used different thread in calling DatabaseMultiTenantProvider, "[DEBUG] 25-02-2021 21:07:22.081 | [Hibernate Search - Mass indexing - Users - ID loading - 0] | DatabaseMultiTenantProvider  | connecting to tenent: my2ndDS
"

Comment: Yes, Hibernate Search uses multiple threads when mass indexing. I said that much in my answer :) In any case, if you're getting the same problem with your "updated(1)" code, it means the problem is unrelated to Hibernate Search. It looks there's something wrong with retrieving the datasource from a new thread in Payara. I'd suggest you investigate that.

Comment: I can solve now. The problem when Hibernate Search in Mass Indexing mode (will take high CPU), can't use InitContext.lookup in getting dataSource. When disable MassIndexer, the Hibernate Search can use InitContext.lookup. So at this time I use a hardcode dataSource. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. update the class DatabaseMultiTenantProvider in getConnection method (see below),
2. can use the PersistanceContext the same as begining (no need to use a ThreadLocal).

   ```
   @Override
   public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
      //Just use the multitenancy if the hibernate.multiTenancy == DATABASE
      logger.debug("connecting to tenent DS: {}", () -> tenantIdentifier);
       if (TENANT_SUPPORTED.equals(typeTenancy)) {
        try {

                logger.debug("use tenant dataSource name: {}", () -> tenantIdentifier);
                //final String tenant[] = tenantIdentifier.split(":{2}");
                //if (tenant != null && tenant.length > 1) { 
                final MariaDbDataSource mds = new MariaDbDataSource();
                if (tenantIdentifier.equals("myDS")) {
                    logger.debug("using 1st dataSource: {}", () -> tenantIdentifier);
                    mds.setUrl("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/mtDb");
                    mds.setUser("mtII");
                    mds.setPassword("mt123");
                    mds.setServerName("localhost");
                    mds.setPort(3306);
                    mds.setDatabaseName("mtDb");
                } else if (tenantIdentifier.equals("my2ndDS")) {
                    logger.debug("using 2nd database: {}", () -> tenantIdentifier);
                    mds.setUrl("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/mt2Db");
                    mds.setUser("mtII");
                    mds.setPassword("mt123");
                    mds.setServerName("localhost");
                    mds.setPort(3306);
                    mds.setDatabaseName("mt2Db");
                }
                dataSource = mds;
                return dataSource.getConnection();
                /* } else {
                        logger.debug("normal way in connecting to dataSource");
                        final String dsURL = "java:app/jdbc/" + tenantIdentifier;
                        logger.debug("getConnection for: {}", () -> dsURL);
                        final Context init = new InitialContext();
                        dataSource = (DataSource) init.lookup(dsURL);
                        return dataSource.getConnection();
                    }*/
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                throw new HibernateException("Error trying to get dataSource ['java:app/jdbc/" + tenantIdentifier + "']", e);
            }
        }
        return null;
   ```

}